# Program complies even when we do not handle the checked Exception thrown by Frame constructor?

Tags: java, exception, awt, checked-exceptions

As per Oracle Documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#Frame()

Frame constructor throws HeadlessException - when GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true

But the program runs without handling the Exception when the constructor is called

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MouseDemo extends Frame{
    String msg="";

    MouseDemo()
    {
        super();//not handling HeadlessException
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                msg="Clicked";
                repaint();

            }

        });

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } );
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(msg, 50, 50);
    }
    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        MouseDemo obj=new MouseDemo();
        obj.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        obj.setTitle("hello");
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

    
}
```

MouseDemo() neither handle the HeadlessException nor throws it to the calling method then why are we not getting compilation error

Comment: `HeadlessException` is not a checked exception.

Comment: Best to look things up in the API *before* asking questions that are answered by looking things up in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [§8.4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6) of the Java Language Specification puts it,

> It is permitted but not required to mention unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) in a `throws` clause.

So not everything you see in a `throws` clause is a checked exception. In fact, checked exceptions are defined in [§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1):

> `RuntimeException` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the run-time exception classes.
>
> The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are `Throwable` and all its subclasses other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.

If you look at `HeadlessException`'s inheritance tree, you will see that it is a subclass of `RuntimeException`:

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
      java.lang.RuntimeException
        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
          java.awt.HeadlessException
```

Therefore, it is an unchecked exception, and you are not required to handle it with either a `try...catch` or another `throws` clause.